# VS2010 Intellisense behavior change (not fixed by ctrl-alt-space)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

All of a sudden I've lost automatic Intellisense in my projects.  And now I'm doubting I ever had it because it's something I just took for granted.

Now, if I type in System. nothing pops up automatically until I hit ctrl-space.

I've tried the suggested "ctrl-alt-space" to toggle intellisense Completion Mode, but that only adds or removes a search box at the top of the Intellisense window, which I still have to bring up with "ctrl-space"

Am I crazy?  Isn't the default mode of Intellisense to popup suggestions after you type in object. ?

Comment: Hans's answer is the one that worked for me, but I'm sure that Thomas Li's answer will work for someone else.  I also believe that this was due to an addon that was over-aggressive.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a setting, it could be turned off if you recently played with an add-on that you subsequently uninstalled.  For example.  Tools + Options, Text Editor, All Languages.  Ensure the "Auto list members" checkbox is ticked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C#, go to Tools -> Text Editor -> C# -> IntelliSense. Make sure "Show completion list after a character is typed" is checked.